# drawing 2 red balls from box contains 3 red balls and 7 white balls

Tags: probability, combinations

I have tried to find a solution for this problem a lot but I couldn't solve it.

Consider a box containing 3 red ball and 7 white balls. Suppose that balls are drawn one at a time, at random, without replacement from this box until two red balls are obtained. Let X denote the number of the draw on which the second red ball is obtained. Find the probability mass function of X

all what I could do is to get the range for X.
where X = 2 , 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Just go one by one.  Easy to see that $P(X=2)=\frac 3{10}\times \frac 2{9}$ for example.  Now do the rest.

Comment: the problem here is i can't know how many times i will draw balls so i can not decide the probability very well.

Comment: maybe i will draw one red ball then 3 white balls then another red ball
i won't draw two red balls after each other

Comment: It's really not that hard.  Try some of the cases and I think you'll get the idea.  In any case, people here will meet you half way if you show a little effort.  What's $P(X=3)$ for instance?

Comment: okay I think it will be (((3C1)*(7C1))/(10C2))*2/8

Comment: Good!  And that principle should generalize nicely to the other cases.  I'll pst something below so you can check your result, but I think you can finish it from here.

Comment: I got it , thank you so much , i created a formula now for the problem
and i learned a new strategy when i can't find the solution for something :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's compute $P(X=i)$.

To be in that scenario, the first $i-1$ choices must consist of exactly $1$ red and $i-2$ whites.  There are $\binom 7{i-2}$ ways to choose the whites and $3$ ways to choose the reds.  Thus there are $3\times \binom 7{i-2}$ ways to choose the first $i-1$. Of course there are $\binom {10}{i-1}$ ways to do it with out restriction.  Thus the probability that the first $i-1$ contain exactly $1$ red is $$3\times \binom 7{i-2}\Big /\binom {10}{i-1}$$

Having successfully chosen the first $i-1$ we now require that the $i^{th}$ choice be red.  That has probability $\frac 2{10-(i-1)}=\frac 2{11-i}$.  Thus the answer is $$\left(3\times \binom 7{i-2}\Big /\binom {10}{i-1}\right)\times \frac 2{11-i}$$